# How to get Properties from JSON encoded array in javascript from PHP?

Tags: php, json, object

I can't for the life of me get the values out from a JSON encoded array in javascript from PHP?

```
$company = new stdClass();
$company->PostCode   = $orgs->Organisation[$i]->BookingCategory->BookingDetails->OrganisationPostCode;
$company->Name       = $orgs->Organisation[$i]->OrganisationName;
$company->Address1   = $orgs->Organisation[$i]->BookingCategory->BookingDetails->OrganisationAddress1;
$company->Address2   = $orgs->Organisation[$i]->BookingCategory->BookingDetails->OrganisationAddress2;

array_push($myArr,$company);
$someJSON = json_encode($myArr);
echo $someJSON;
```

That gives me this which is returned

```
[{"PostCode":{"0":"mypostcode"},"Name":{"0":"mycomanyname"},"Address1":{"0":"myaddress1"},"Address2":{"0":"myaddress2"}}]
```

I've tried this and other permutations in xmlhttprequest:

```
var JSONObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for (var key in JSONObject) {
    postcode = JSONObject[key][0]["PostCode"].PostCode
}
```

Some code omitted such as the loop etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried out `postcode = JSONObject[key]["PostCode"]["0"]` ?

Comment: Just a tip for the future. I find it often helps me to `console.log(JSONObject);` so I can visually see how the object/array-structure actually looks like. Also if needed you can then copy/paste it in a JSON prettifier for easy reading

Answer (score 0):

considering your code you have to do

```
var JSONObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for (var key in JSONObject) {
  postcode = JSONObject[key].PostCode[0];
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `postcode = JSONObject[key].PostCode[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the protocol is regarding finding my own answer,so sorry if this is incorrect.  I managed to get the values out like this, posting for others:

```
JSONObject[key]["PostCode"][0]
```